# Inserting Images into Flexslider using Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, flexslider

I have flexsider on my site and I want to pull my linked images into it to show a dynamic slide show. However my current setup works but not all the time it shows sometimes. How can I rectify this issue. I pull the image and its link from JSON webservice. My code is below:

Ajax //load list on featuredtracks page

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforeshow", "#pagename", function( e ) {
 //ajax stuff
});

//callback function 
  function pagenamecallback(rtndata) 
 { 
   rtndata;
   var data= $("#featured");
   for(j=0;j<=songs.length -1;j++)
   {
         var a = $("<a href='./page.html' data-transition='fade'><img src='"+ rtndata[j].track_art_url + "' style='width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: auto;' alt='featuredimage'></a>");

    data.append($("<li></li>").append(a));
}

}
```

JS

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#pagename", function( e ) {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    randomize: true,
    animation: "slide"
});
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides" id="featured">
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: This Looks like a race condition between pagebeforeshow , ajax call time taken and page show . have you tried putting the flexslider initialization code at the end of pagenamecallback function ?

Comment: No I have not will give it a try

Comment: yeah, you have to change your structure, sometimes you ajax call will finish after pageshow, so wait for ajax to finish and then do initialize your slider

Comment: This works fine I initialize the slider in the callback after receiving the data